# Stack Overflow should create a proper responsible disclosure portal or at least provide an email address

Tags: feature-request, bug-reporting-process

Today, I identified a bug on a Stack Exchange company website (domain name contains `stackoverflow`) that has privacy implications for certain users (not a super big thing, but an unnecessary privacy violation for at least a few people - I will post more information about the bug once SO has had time to address the issue).

When I looked for how to disclose this issue responsibly, I was surprised to find that there is no dedicated "responsible disclosure" form or email address. The best I could find was submit a "contact us" issue as "other>other", which is very unspecific.

Of course I reported the issue anyway, through the contact form.

I would like to urge management to set up a proper email address/form for responsible disclosure issues and provide a bit more information than given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports):

> #### How do I report a possible security vulnerability?
>
> We take security vulnerabilities very seriously and work hard to
> provide a secure online experience for our users. If you believe you
> have discovered a security issue that affects many users, please
> report it to us so we can investigate and correct the problem.
>
> **Do not** post reports of security vulnerabilities on our meta site; **please [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly** instead. Include as much information as you can about the issue and
> detailed instructions about how to reproduce it.

The current information on disclosure is scant. It would be good if something like the following could be used instead: https://www.redditinc.com/policies/bug-bounty-program

About 13 hours after I submitted the contact form, I received the following email:

> Hi there,
>
> Thank you for writing to us – your ticket has been escalated to our Trust & Safety team. You should hear from them in the next few days, but it might take longer to get a response.
>
> Please know that they’ll be working on it and will reach out if they have any questions or once there is a resolution.
>
> All the best,
> Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Support Team.

**Update:** I've posted details on the privacy issue and SO's response on meta SE (where this post should have gone in the first place): [stackoverflow.blog used to deanonymize commenters through gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391809/stackoverflow-blog-used-to-deanonymize-commenters-through-gravatars)

Comment: Could you add a paragraph why it would be better to have a separate reporting system for security vulnerabilities compared to just using the Contact Us form?

Comment: You found a "privacy vulnerability" **today**; reported it **today**; and you feel that **today** is sufficiently long for the company to address the issue and ship a fix, such that you feel it's right to disclose this security vulnerability **today**??!!!?? Public disclosure on the same day as discovery and reporting seems like an *incredibly short* period of time in which to expect a fix to be implemented and shipped. While some *few* things might be appropriate to publicly disclose in that timeframe, I'd suggest following industry norms with respect to reporting and public disclosure.

Comment: @Makyen While a little premature, this post does not disclose what the vulnerability _is_. I just hope it's not another thing that doesn't actually affect privacy, like how we lost the granularity of 'last active' due to "privacy" last year.

Comment: @Makyen Are you aware that I haven't said anything other than that it's a bug that affects privacy? Do you feel that is too much? Re industry standards, wouldn't it be helpful if those were included in the help center article?

Comment: @TylerH and Cornelius Of course I'm aware that you haven't described the vulnerability, but you said "I will post more information about the bug in a bit once SO has had time to address the issue", which *strongly* implied to me that you expected to post more about the vulnerability in a *very short* timeframe, rather than a timeframe consistent with industry norms, which I don't think I'd ever describe as "in a bit", as "normal" timeframes for that are *far longer* than what I'd consider to be "in a bit".

Comment: @Makyen I was sloppy in my writing, "will tell you more in a bit" could mean minutes or weeks. I've edited to state that I will share publicly in a week unless I hear back from the company. This should be a very simple fix, so a week seems the right time frame.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks yes, good points, good to explain to me that I should wait an appropriate amount of time. It would be really helpful if this was laid out on said help center page.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on MSE, or am I missing something? This question is about the help center / contact us page that's on every Stack Exchange site, right? Not specific to Stack Overflow (the programming Q&A)?

Comment: "submit a "contact us" issue as "other>other", which is very unspecific." That it's very unspecific is probably their problem. That they likely won't read it also. Just submit your report, wait some reasonable time and then publish it or not and go on. Let them deal with the fallout. It's not your problem.

Comment: I really could've sworn that there was a `security@stackexchange.com` or something at some point, but I must've dreamt it. Even the [security hall of fame page](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) refers exclusively to the Contact Us form.

Comment: @TylerH 'I just hope it's not another thing that doesn't actually affect privacy, like how we lost the granularity of 'last active' due to "privacy" last year.' No it's not that at all. It should have little impact on anyone here as it's probably not a part of the page anyone spends much time. But it's a clear and unnecessary deanonymization in violation of what is promised. Once it's fixed, the deanonymization will not be reversible as it will have been saved in archive.org.

Answer (score 18):

I disagree that we need a new feature based on pure speculation that contacts through "contact us" form are completely ignored. If it is indeed the case that communications are ignored I see even less reasons for yet another way to "contact us" to have that ignored too.

Comment: They seem to not be able to follow up on every contact ["While we could not recover all of the GPT suspension appeals sent to the Stack Exchange inbox..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes)

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution that was more about extracting the support requests about GPT suspensions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes#comment1301183_389928 Although I would agree that sometimes they don't read our reports properly. I'd reported a proxy site once and in reply received the stock message about them not being able to handle duplicated content...

Comment: I remember several similar Threads on 'Meta-SO' and still "*[We'll respond] in the next few days, but it might take longer*" = no time-span, sounds very vague to me... // There should be an [so].com/text or /security or /security.txt, I don't remember the "Standard", "standard to report a security incident" yields useless Results on 'Google'...

Comment: The de-facto standard would be /.well-known/security.txt (See https://securitytxt.org/ or RFC 9116) but let's be honest - Most people reading this comment will most likely see this for the first time so that wouldn't really do anything either.